# How to change speech synthesizer voice or speed during speech in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, text-to-speech

I have a slider and a list of available voices that I want to allow the user to change on the fly during speech synthesis using the [SpeechSynthesizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8) class. I am able to do all of that before speech starts using `SpeechSynthesizer.Options.SpeakingRate` and `SpeechSynthesizer.Voice`. However, I want the user to be able to change these settings while speech is occurring.

Changing the properties while speech synthesis is running `async` doesn't work. I've tried to create a `new SpeechSynthesizer()` and changing the voice, but that doesn't change the original synthesis as it is running either. I know this is possible, because it is done in Microsoft Edge. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> I know this is possible, because it is done in Microsoft Edge.

First of all, I'm not sure how Microsoft Edge achieves this function. It is very likely that the edge is not using this API.

I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer) and tested the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis), I have not found the options that we can modify the Voice and SpeakingRate during the speech starts. So this function should be impossible for UWP.

Comment: I think that Edge tracks how many characters/words the engine has spoken, and restarts with a new speech synth at that point using the modified settings. That's what I'll try out anyway. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

The speech synthesizer contains SpeechSynthesizer.Rate Property.

{
// Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

```
  // Set a value for the speaking rate.  
  synth.Rate = -2;  

  // Configure the audio output.   
  synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();  

  // Speak a text string synchronously.  
  synth.Speak("This example speaks a string with the speaking rate set to -2.");
```

}

Comment: Not sure if it has been removed, but this isn't present in the current version (1.16).